# Reading a response of an APDU command

Tags: java, smartcard, apdu

I am trying to read data from a file in a smart card, I'm using the following APDU command

```
00 B0 00 02 00
```

but I get this response:

```
A1 1B 4F 0C A0 00 00 00 77 02 08 05 04 49 44 01 50 07 43 4E 49 2D 43 53 45 51 02 10 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 90 00
```

How can I convert or read this value in hexadecimal encoding?

Answer (score 4):

The last two bytes make up the status word (SW), first the `90` and then  the `00`. The rest is the hexadecimal encoding of the binary data in the file.

It looks like the contents however are ASN.1 BER encoded. So you need to BER decode the response. BER is TLV (Tag Length Value). So the first two bytes are tag and value, `A1 1B`. The meaning of the text is context specific (so look up the specification for this specific file). So your file actually contains 2 + `1B` bytes, or 29 bytes, the rest have been left to their default value `00`.

BER decoding is specified in ISO 7816-4 which you really should get to understand anything about file based smart cards. Also take a look at the [Wikipedia page about ASN.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One) and take a look at the decoded value [here](http://lapo.it/asn1js/#A11B4F0CA000000077020805044944015007434E492D43534551021001).

Comment: Seems: 4F - AID TLV, contains Oberthur's application (RID=A000000077). 50 - application label "CNI-CSE".

Comment: Didn't expect a comment on this after so long on this particular one, especially since the org. asker seems to have abandoned it (shame on you, Anass) but yeah, more info [here](http://lapo.it/asn1js/#A11B4F0CA000000077020805044944015007434E492D43534551021001)

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow TS 11.11, TS 11.14, TS 03.48.

http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/100900_100999/100977/08.14.00_60/ts_100977v081400p.pdf

http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/101200_101299/101267/08.18.00_60/ts_101267v081800p.pdf

http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/101100_101199/101181/08.09.00_60/ts_101181v080900p.pdf